If $(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3})=-2$ find $(x+\frac{1}{x})$

If $\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)=-2$, find $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

I apologize if my question has already been posed here but I have tried searching online for a solution but I was unable to find anything as all the results I got were going from $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) =$ some number and to find $\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$ which is quite simple with identities. This question is however the opposite.
I was able to find using a standard identity that $$\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3-3 \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
so with $s= \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$
$$-2=s^3-3s\\0=s^3-3s+2$$
And so I found $s=1$ is and $-1,0,2,3$ are not but I am unable to find all the solutions and I am unsure how to go about doing that.

Good work.  $~(s^3 - 3s + 2) \div (s-1) = (s^2 + s - 2),~$ which factors into $~(s + 2) \times (s - 1).~$ So, $~s=1~$ is a repeated root and there is the third root $~s=-2.$

As polynomials, $ s^3 - 3s + 2 = (s-1) (?????)$

If it is assumed $x$ is real, this means the only solution is $2.$

@ThomasAndrews I believe you mean the only solution is $-2$, which occurs with $x=-1$.

Rational root theorem can find $s=-2$ as an additional root then Vieta, division, or checking $p'(1)$ will verify the double root

Whoops, yes.${}{}{}{}$

Keyword : reciprocal equations

Just for your interest, putting the quadratic coefficient 0 in tartaglia’s formula gets you a bit clear solution in such form of cubic equation, which is quite renowned.

You have already found that $s:=x+\tfrac1x$ satisfies
$$s^3-3s+2=0,$$
and that $s=1$ is a solution to this cubic. That means
$$s^3-3s+2=(s-1)P(s),$$
for some quadratic polynomial $P$, and by long division we find that
$$s^3-3s+2=(s-1)(s^2+s-2),$$
so it remains to find the solutions to
$$s^2+s-2=0.$$
Of course with the quadratic formula we find the solutions $s=1$ and $s=-2$.
Note that $s=1$ is impossible if $x$ is real; solving for $x$ leaves us with solving
$$x+\tfrac1x=1,\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x+\tfrac1x=-2.$$
This boils down to solving two quadratic equations in $x$; multiplying both by $x$ yields
$$x^2-x+1=0,\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x^2+2x+1=0.$$
Again by the quadratic formula, we find the complex solutions $x=\tfrac12\pm\tfrac12\sqrt{3}i$ to the former, and the unique real solution $x=-1$ to the latter.

A more direct approach to solving $x^3+\tfrac{1}{x^3}=2$ would be to immediately clear denominators to get
$$x^6+1=-2x^3,\qquad\text{ and so }\qquad (x^3+1)^2=0,$$
from which we immediately get the three solutions found above.

This is an excellent answer, but I just want to comment that with $x+\frac{1}{x}=1$, it's also fairly easy to see that $x\gt 0$, so then either $x\ge 1$ or $\frac{1}{x}\ge 1$, so the LHS is $\gt 1$, i.e., there is no real solution.

@JohnOmielan Indeed it is well-known that if $x>0$ then $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2.$

Given : $\left(x^{3}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)=-2$
Now $\left(x^{3}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)$ can be written as $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3}-3(x)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$
$\implies \left(x^{3}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3}-3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$
Which means
$$u^{3}-3u=-2$$ where $u=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$
$\implies u^{3}-3u+2=0$
By trial and error method we get $u=1$. Because if $u=1$ then $1^{3}-3(1)+2=0$.
Therefore now let's substitute back $u$.
Therefore $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=1$
Also, it is clear that $-2$ is also a root of the equation $u^{3}-3u+2=0$
Because if you divide $u^{3}-3u+2$ by $u-1$ then the quotient is $u^{2}+u-2$. And $u^{2}+u-2=(u-1)(u+2)$ which implies $-2$ is also a root of this equation.
Therefore $u=-2$ which implies $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=-2$

Welcome to Math SE. Note that $u^3-3u+2=0$ is a cubic equation, so it has $3$ roots. Thus, $1$ is not the only root, as the question comments indicate, and if $x$ is expected to be real, then $u=1$ is not the appropriate result to be using.

Yes exactly. So, I edited the answer

It's better now, but you still have not indicated what the third root is (as indicated in the comments, it's a repeated root of $u=1$). Also, for completeness, you may wish to show that, if $x$ is meant to be real, then $u=-2$ is the only valid solution.

Quick remark : You don't need trial and error to find $u=1$. Hit the cubic with the rational root theorem.

But in the question it is not mentioned that $x$ is real

Assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\ne 0$, you have that:
$$-2=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{x^6+1}{x^3}\Longrightarrow x^6+2x^3+1=0 \iff (x^3+1)^2=0 \iff x=-1$$
Therefore, $$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=-2$$

I have a fully different proof, with just setting a function $f(x)=-x^3$.
Then we can say that $x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}=-\left( f(x)+\dfrac{1}{f(x)} \right) = -2.$
So, $f(x)+\dfrac{1}{f(x)} = 2$, and $f(x)$ is bijective in $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$.
So we can say that $f(x)>0$ and $f(x)=1$ with the AM-GM Inequality, which implies $x=-1$.
